# How do I set min and max tasks for auto scaling policy for ecs services using the SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I want to utilize the AWS SDK to set and define min/max tasks for my auto scaling policy for my ECS service.

So I'm able to successfully modify my auto scaling group policy for my ECS containers instances using code.

```java
UpdateAutoScalingGroupRequest request = new UpdateAutoScalingGroupRequest().withAutoScalingGroupName("helloWorld-ASG").withMinSize(1);

UpdateAutoScalingGroupResult response = client.updateAutoScalingGroup(request);

UpdateScalingPlanResult scalingResponse = scalingClient.updateScalingPlan(scalingRequest);
```

but how do I do this for the auto scaling policy for my ECS service?
What classes do I need to do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

For ECS service auto scaling look at the [AWSApplicationAutoScalingClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/applicationautoscaling/AWSApplicationAutoScalingClient.html), [PutScalingPolicyRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/applicationautoscaling/model/PutScalingPolicyRequest.html) and [PutScalingPolicyResult](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/applicationautoscaling/model/PutScalingPolicyResult.html) classes, then depending on your preferred scaling policy you will need either the [StepScalingPolicyConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/applicationautoscaling/model/StepScalingPolicyConfiguration.html) or [TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/applicationautoscaling/model/TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration.html) class.

See the following example taken from the AWS Java SDK docs:

```
AWSApplicationAutoScaling client = AWSApplicationAutoScalingClientBuilder.standard().build();
PutScalingPolicyRequest request = new PutScalingPolicyRequest()
        .withPolicyName("web-app-cpu-gt-75")
        .withServiceNamespace("ecs")
        .withResourceId("service/default/web-app")
        .withScalableDimension("ecs:service:DesiredCount")
        .withPolicyType("StepScaling")
        .withStepScalingPolicyConfiguration(
                new StepScalingPolicyConfiguration().withAdjustmentType("PercentChangeInCapacity")
                        .withStepAdjustments(new StepAdjustment().withMetricIntervalLowerBound(0d).withScalingAdjustment(200)).withCooldown(60));
PutScalingPolicyResult response = client.putScalingPolicy(request);AWSApplicationAutoScaling client = AWSApplicationAutoScalingClientBuilder.standard().build();
```

Comment: I see. I'm looking through the documentation but can't find anything on the min/max tasks. I can set desiredCount with the UpdateServiceRequest but not the min/max task.

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm in a blue/green deployment and I'm struggling to find in the documentation where to set min/max tasks for that. I looked at DeploymentConfiguration but it seems like the withMinimumHealthyPercent() function is only for rolling update. Currently looking at CodeDeploy because that's where B/G is used but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

This answer above was for version 1.x of the SDK for version 2.x of the SDK you would need something like this one:

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/index.html?software/amazon/awssdk/services/applicationautoscaling/ApplicationAutoScalingClient.html